# Incompatible types error when trying to pass a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors

I'm trying to pass a 2d array into another method, but it keeps giving me the error "int cannot be converted to int[][]", and the opposite for the return line. When I remove the [][] from the Deal method, it gives me the error but in reverse saying "int[][] cannot be converted to int". What am I doing wrong here?

```
//2-6 players face eachother in a game of Go Fish!

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random; //RNG

public class GoFish{
public static void main(String []args){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("This is a game simulation of Go Fish! It supports up to 6 players.");
   int Players = 0;
   System.out.println("How many players will be playing?");
   Players = in.nextInt();          //# of players
   while(Players < 2 || Players > 6){
      System.out.println("Please enter a number of players, between 2 and 6");
      Players = in.nextInt();
   }
   int [][] Cards = new int[Players + 1][54]; //Array for the cards. Final entry is the number of cards within the hand/deck, second to last number is the number of points.
   String [] Deck = new String [52];//This Array will contain the name for each card.
   Cards [0][52] = 52;              //Array 0 is the deck, Array 1 is the hand for player 1, Array 2 is the hand for player 2, ect.
   for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){     //Fill the deck with cards.
      Cards [0][i] = 1;
   }
   int n = 5;                       //Number of cards to deal to the users.
   if(Players == 2)
      n = 7;                        //Increases to 7 if only 2 players are playing.
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){      //Deal cards for both players.
      for(int j = 0; j < Players; j++){
         Cards = Deal(Cards, Deck, Players);
      }
   }
}

static int Deal(int Cards[][], String Deck[], int Players){
return Cards;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Deal` supposed to do?

Comment: Right now it does nothing, in the future it will modify the cards in the deck, and the hand of the player who is drawing a card, then return the modified array.

Comment: Change the return type of `Deal` to `int[][]`, i.e `static int[][] Deal(int Cards[][], String Deck[], int Players){ return Cards;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Deal` returns **int** but you defined Cards as: **int [][]** Cards.

Comment: How is it returning int? Cards within the method is defined as int Cards [][]; the error on the return line says "incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int". If modify the return line to "return Cards[][];" It gives me a .class error. EDIT: I see my error, I need to add the [][] to the function itself, thanks :)

Comment: @Surav: yes it was very confusing to see the error. I also had trouble to find what's wrong at the first moment.